# Is there a way to map a Date column to a string property in EF?

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I know I can solve this by adding another property to my entity which will contain the conversion between types but was wondering if it is possible with EF CF.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need this for UI presentation (of the `DateTime` value) reasons?

If so, you might want to consider defining a separate View model class, and using something like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to map the properties between the two.

Comment: It is for my domain. I am heavily using AutoMapper, good one.

Comment: Basically I need to implement the same interface for some of my entities and underlying tables have slight differences. Changing table columns are not an option although I think it would be the best solution. I can use additional properties to solve this but doing at the mapping layer would be cleaner.